# python split and reverse text file

Tags: python, reverse, flip

I have a text file which stores data like `name : score` e.g.:

> bob : 10
>   fred : 3
>   george : 5

However, I want to make it so it says

> 10 : bob
>   3 : fred
>   5 : george

What would the code be to flip it like that?
Would I need to separate them first by removing the colon as I have managed this through this code?

```
file = open("Class 3.txt", "r")
t4 = (file.read())
test =''.join(t4.split(':')[0:10])
print (test)
```

How would I finish it and make it say the reverse?

Comment: Is it `bob : 10` or `bob:10`?

Comment: its the first one with a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code handles fractional scores (e.g. `9.5`), and doesn't care whether there are extra spaces around the `:` delimiter. It should be much easier to maintain than your current code.

**Class 3.txt:**

```
bob : 10
fred : 3
george : 5
```

**Code:**

```
class_num = input('Which class (1, 2, or 3)? ')
score_sort = input('Sort by name or score? ').lower().startswith('s')

with open("Class " + class_num + ".txt", "r") as f:
    scores = {name.strip():float(score) for
              name,score in (line.strip().split(':') for line in f)}
    if score_sort:
        for name in sorted(scores, key=scores.get, reverse=True):
            print(scores.get(name), ':', name)
    else:
        for name in sorted(scores):
            print(name, ':', scores.get(name))
```

**Input:**

```
3
scores
```

**Output:**

```
10.0 : bob
5.0 : george
3.0 : fred
```

**Input:**

```
3
name
```

**Output:**

```
bob : 10.0
fred : 3.0
george : 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is going to be a lot harder to do whole-file-at-once than line-at-a-time.

But, either way, you obviously can't just `split(':')` and then `''.join(…)`. All that's going to do is replace colons with nothing. You obviously need `':'.join(…)` to put the colons back in.

And meanwhile, you have to swap the values around on each side of each colon.

So, here's a function that takes just one line, and swaps the sides:

```
def swap_sides(line):
    left, right = line.split(':')
    return ':'.join((right, left))
```

But you'll notice there's a few problems here. The `left` has a space before the colon; the `right` has a space after the colon, and a newline at the end. How are you going to deal with that?

The simplest way is to just `strip` out all the whitespace on both sides, then add back in the whitespace you want:

```
def swap_sides(line):
    left, right = line.split(':')
    return ':'.join((right.strip() + ' ', ' ' + left.strip())) + '\n'
```

But a smarter idea is to treat the space around the colon as part of the delimiter. (The newline, you'll still need to handle manually.)

```
def swap_sides(line):
    left, right = line.strip().split(' : ')
    return ' : '.join((right.strip(), left.strip())) + '\n'
```

But if you think about it, do you really need to add the newline back on? If you're just going to pass it to `print`, the answer is obviously no. So:

```
def swap_sides(line):
    left, right = line.strip().split(' : ')
    return ' : '.join((right.strip(), left.strip()))
```

Anyway, once you're happy with this function, you just write a loop that calls it once for each line. For example:

```
with open("Class 3.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        swapped_line = swap_sides(line)
        print(swapped_line)
```

Comment: You need to wrap the arguments to join in `()` or `[]` because it takes a single iterable.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Guh… thanks. :) I originally had them in a list `t4s` and then passed `t4s[::-1]`, but then decided that wasn't worth explaining here, and broke it when I tuple-unpacked the list…

Comment: [It gets me too.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87139/basic-functions-sum-len-etc-with-recursively-flattened-arguments#comment157640_87139)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I think whether or not it gets me each time depends on whether I've more recently used `max` or `sum`. :)

Comment: see i was trying to sort my actual code out if you look at my other thread i have it will explain better what i was trying to do i tried breaking it down and do it but it didnt seem to work could you please check out my other thread see if you have any ideas

Comment: Why supply your own newline and suppress print's?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Yeah, that is kind of silly; let me re-edit.

Comment: Alternatively: `''.join(s.partition(' : ')[::-1])` (or similar - you know what I mean :p)

Answer (score 0):

Let's learn how to reverse a single line:

```
line = `bob : 10`
line.partition(' : ')  # ('10', ' : ', 'bob')
''.join(reversed(line.partition(' : '))  # 'bob : 10'
```

Now, combine with reading lines from a file:

```
for line in open('Class 3.txt').read().splitlines():
    print ''.join(reversed(line.partition(' : '))
```

## Update

I am re-writing the code to read the file, line by line:

```
with open('Class 3.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        print ''.join(reversed(line.partition(' : ')))
```

Comment: Note that `file` is no longer a builtin in 3.x, and `open` was already recommended when both existed for this purpose anyway....

Comment: @JonClements -- Changed from `file` to `open`. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome - also - since files are iterable over (line by line)... you can just do `for line in open('Class 3.txt')` then `print ''.join(reversed(line.partition(' : ')))` that doesn't require reading the whole file into memory, then breaking it into a list and then iterating over that list... It certainly won't matter in this case - but it's always good to promote good practice to the people attempting to learn on the site :) (could even throw in a use of the `with` statement here!)